# How to prevent particular function from running on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile-website

I have a website that allows users to purchase groceries online. When someone clicks on a product, a cart slides in to show the quantity, price and product name. This works fine on desktop devices but on mobile, the cart covers most of the screen when it slides in. I want to change it so that if a user is on mobile, the cart animation does not run.

My javascript code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.cartButton', function(){

    addToCart(); // function to add item to cart 
    openCart(); // function to run animation to slide cart in
}
```

Comment: check the `screen size` .then passing your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

*google chrome `F12` mode .you get the screen size* 
[image]

Below `425px` width its a mobile screen size.so action only perform above `425px`

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.cartButton', function(){
    console.log($(this).width())
    if($(this).width() > 425){
        addToCart();
        openCart(); 
        }
    })
```

Comment: *"Below 425px width its a mobile"* Well, probably. For now. The key thing isn't whether it's a mobile, it's whether the cart is too big for the screen.

Answer (score 2):

> but on mobile, the cart covers most of the screen when it slides in

So it's not really a mobile thing, it's a screen-size thing.

I'd use CSS media queries to make the cart appropriate for the screen it's being displayed on. Or to keep it hidden if the screen is too small for it.

But you can check the size of the screen via the [`screen` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen)'s `width` and `height` properties and make a decision about what to do with the cart.